# Dynamically Pull Docker Image using chef recipe

Tags: docker, chef-infra, dockerfile, chef-recipe

What Chef-Recipe should do-

1-  Install Docker service.
2-  Dynamically Pull Docker Image; Count depends on User request.
3-  Dynamically Run Docker Containers; Count depends on User request.

What below Chef-recipe is doing-

1-  Install Docker service.
2-  Pull Docker Image; 
3-  Run Docker Containers;

Chef-docker recipe-

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: chef-docker
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright 2016, SONATA_SOFTWARE
#
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#
docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end
# Pull latest image
docker_image 'centos' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end
# Run container 
docker_container 'first' do
  repo 'centos'
  command '/bin/bash'
  tty true
  action :run
  end  
  docker_container 'second' do
  repo 'centos'
  command '/bin/bash'
  tty true
  action :run
  end
```

I am clueless on how to call/pull "n" no# of image and "n" no# of container dynamically or from outside recipe on user request. Any insight on this will help me.

Comment: Chef is not done for interactive behavior. It is supposed to describe a desired state for the system. You may write your user request in attribute file and loop over, but I'm unsure of what you're after.

Comment: @Tensibai I want to Dynamically Pull an Image of user request using Chef-recipe.I mean to say that,the above recipe will Pull image of only CentOs. But I am looking for an approach where I can Pull an Image of my wish.i:e,CentOs or Ubuntu,etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well you would use a data_bag for that, and then look over the data_bag items like "containers and pull / start per containers.

Look at this very good example in the docs https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#create-users

In their case they loop over a data_bag which defines users, and then create those one by on.

So a user request is an entry in the data_bag for that particular node

Comment: Is there any other alternate solution for this

Comment: yes you can also use e.g. node attributes as a hashmap or a wrapper cookbook. But in those cases the user needs access to either the node.json (chef zero) or to the chef-server ( chef-client ). Probably not very matchy to "on user request"